# does ucanaccess driver handle multiple concurrent java applications?

Tags: java, tomcat, ucanaccess

Will the UCanAccess driver work properly in a scenario with a Java application, a webapp running under Tomcat and users who might open the MS Access GUI all possibly doing updates to the database?

Both the Java appl and the webapp would use the UCanAccess driver.  Although the Java application is the primary source of updates, and the webapp is primarily just reading/presenting data, there can be scenarios where any of 3 could perform an update. I am currently using the Sun JDBC-ODBC bridge but looking for a replacement.

Not sure how the app and the webapp would stay in sync other than using the options KeepMirror (and Memory=false). Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 3):

I can just say that this scenario **is not absolutely supported by ucanaccess**. You can just have one app that writes on the db, otherwise you risk the db corruption. See also the Openexclusive connection setting in the ucanaccess website. Also the options you mentioned are unrelated to the issue.

Comment: A way to bypass this limitation would be setting up a single data service (with UCanAcess) responsible for all DB interactions and calling this service from both applications.

Comment: Or just stop to misuse a desktop database and change to a real client server database.

Comment: Is 'is not absolutely supported' meaning 'not fully supported (but is partially supported)' or meaning 'it is not supported at all'?  The Openexclusive option is not what is needed as that would restrict updates to only 1 of the apps.  Doesn't  UCanAccess write changes in the hsqldb back to the mdb/accdb?  Wouldn't using the same mirror (MirrorFolder option) and the KeepMirror option point the java appl and the webapp to the same db? The docs say "the hsqldb will be recreated if access database is modified by a different program" ie GUI so might work acceptably if limited cases?

Comment: The single data service would work.  A real client server db would be nice (and should have known that would be suggested) but is not the configuration for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Dear, obviously ucanaccess writes changes in the hsqldb back to the mdb/accdb.
Concurrent unmediated write operations on the same file may corrupt the mdb, if they aren't synchronized and so there isn't something in the middle that does it. Openexclusive uses a  Access-like file-based method to synchronize write operations. I implemented it for a reason. Before answering to the rest, why are you using keepMirror?